# SQL with Pareto Frontier

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Table is located in the photo

Question: Solar power and wind power tend to be complementary, since it tends to be less windy when there are few clouds and the sun can best reach solar panels. Our goal in this part is to identify states that strike the best balance between solar and wind energy production. Here we define a state as "best" if it exists on the Pareto frontier of solar and wind energy production. In other words, a state is Pareto optimal if no other state produces both more solar and more wind energy, and the Pareto frontier is the set of states that are Pareto optimal. Write a query that returns the entire Pareto frontier. Results should be triples of the form (state, solar, wind), where state is the name of the state in the frontier, and solar and wind are its solar and wind energy production in MWh. Order the results in descending order by sum total of solar and wind energy production in MWh.

Do explain to me pareto frontier and how I can apply it in sql.

I only know how to do this:

```
SELECT state, solar, wind 
FROM energy 
WHERE solar+wind = (SELECT max(solar+wind) 
                    FROM energy);
```

which doesn't give the full result
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A point `a` belongs to the Pareto Frontier if and only if there is no other point `b` such that

```
b.wind >= a.wind AND b.solar >= a.solar AND ... 
AND (b.wind > a.wind OR b.solar > a.solar OR ...)
```

These conditions together can be rewritten as:

```
b.wind >= a.wind AND b.solar >= a.solar AND ... 
    AND (b.wind + b.solar + ... > a.wind + a.solar + ...)
```

So the SQL is (change the names to fit your needs):

```
SELECT * FROM states a 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM states b 
        WHERE b.wind >= a.wind AND b.solar >= a.solar 
        AND b.wind + b.solar > a.wind + a.solar
    )
```

I am pretty sure that ordering is straightforward from this point.

Here is a small example:

```
create table states (stateid int, wind double, solar double, primary key (stateid))

truncate table states;

insert into states values (1, 100, 30), (2, 120, 50), (3, 150, 30), (4, 100, 60), (5, 150, 40);

select * from states a 
where not exists (
    select * from states b 
    where b.wind >= a.wind and b.solar >= a.solar and b.wind + b.solar > a.wind + a.solar
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> it seems easy, in this case we can use RANK() function to find result. we maybe we can use MAX() function like you, but makes your query very slow and complicated. Check this query and it should make your life easy.

```
SELECT state, solar, wind, RANK() OVER(partition by state order by (solar+wind) desc) AS rank
FROM energy
```

Comment: I got this error when I used your code, do you know why?

`(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error [SQL: 'SELECT state, solar, wind, RANK() OVER(partition by state order by (solar+wind) desc) AS rank\nFROM energy;']`